# I cannot get ID from session in GET method in Next.js 14

Tags: session, next.js

I have created an api route to handle the `getAllAddresses` that the currently logged in user has created. But I only get an empty array. I imagined that req cannot get the ID of the currently logged in user. I checked nextauth configuration and I got the ID.

To be more certain, I console.log the session configuration on nextauth and get the ID as follows:

```
  ~ session ~ session: {
  user: {
    name: 'Nhung Nguyen',
    email: 'nguyennhung9846@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocLg8TfKh72d8RDiUO9xIxR7CTgR4e6hU8WpwTtlXHEDEIg=s96-c',
    id: '65ff0b9c80353678f60e337a'
  },
  expires: '2024-04-27T13:26:30.889Z'
}
```

But on the api route handle getAllAddresses, the session I receive only has name, email, image, no ID. This is my log at api route handle getAllAddresses:

```
 ~ GET ~ session: {
  user: {
    name: 'Nhung Nguyen',
    email: 'nguyennhung9846@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocLg8TfKh72d8RDiUO9xIxR7CTgR4e6hU8WpwTtlXHEDEIg=s96-c'
  }
}
```

**This is my code in api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js**

```
    const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                await connect()

                const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email })

                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error('Đăng nhập không hợp lệ!')
                }

                const comparePassword = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password)

                if (!comparePassword) {
                    throw new Error('Đăng nhập không hợp lệ!')
                }

                return user
            }
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login'
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ profile, account }) {
            if (account.provider === 'google') {
                try {
                    await connect()
                    let user = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email })
                    if (!user) {
                        user = await User.create({
                            email: profile.email,
                            name: profile.name,
                            avatar: profile.image,
                            wishlist: [],
                            cart: [],
                            orders: [],
                            products: []
                        })
                    }
                    return user

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
            return true
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            user && (token.user = user)

            return token
        },
        async session({ session }) {
            const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email })
            // console.log(' ~ session ~ sessionUser:', sessionUser)

            session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString()
            console.log(' ~ session ~ session.user.id:', session.user.id)

            console.log(' ~ session ~ session:', session)

            return session
        }
    }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

**And this is my code at api route handle getAllAddresses**

```
export async function GET(req) {
    try {
        const session = await getServerSession({ req })
        console.log(' ~ GET ~ session:', session)

        if (!session) {
            return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 })
        }
        const getAllAddresses = await Address.find({ userID: session.user.id })

        if (getAllAddresses) {
            return NextResponse.json({
                success: true,
                data: getAllAddresses,
            });
        } else {
            return NextResponse.json({
                success: false,
                message: "failed to get addresses ! Please try again",
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user addresses:', error)
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this problem with both providers? or only google?

Comment: I have problem on both providers

Comment: I guess the problem is coming from the `jwt` callback. try logging the whole data from its argument: `jwt(data){ console.log(data) }`. Maybe the ID is in different object (profile or etc.)

Comment: this is logging of jwt:

Comment:  ~ jwt ~ user: undefined
 ~ jwt ~ token: {
  name: 'Nhung Nguyen',
  email: 'nguyennhung9846@gmail.com',
  picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocLg8TfKh72d8RDiUO9xIxR7CTgR4e6hU8WpwTtlXHEDEIg=s96-c',
  sub: '116349137026424670444',
  user: {
    id: '116349137026424670444',
    name: 'Nhung Nguyen',
    email: 'nguyennhung9846@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocLg8TfKh72d8RDiUO9xIxR7CTgR4e6hU8WpwTtlXHEDEIg=s96-c'
  },
  iat: 1711634027,
  exp: 1714226027,
  jti: '4abb6cb0-e748-46f3-9275-d7cd7f50ed69'
}

Comment: in jwt~token, I already have id, so how can I set the ID? Please, help me

Comment: and which next auth version are you using?

Comment: my version is 4.24.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched more in the Next Auth documentation. I found out that you are using the `getServerSession` incorrectly. In V4 while you are using the App router, you must pass only the next auth options to this function. More information can be found here (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#in-app-router)

However, I will give you en example which you can use it right away in your code.

First of all, you should export the config of the Next Auth. Like this:

```js
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [...],
    session: ...,
    ...
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

After that, you can create a util file called `auth.js` or whatever and put this function in it:

```js
import {authOptions} from "app/api/[...nextauth]/route.js"

export const auth = () => getServerSession(authOptions)
```

Finally, you can import this function wherever you want and call it:

```js
export const POST = async () => {
   const session = await auth();

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a session callback :

```js
callbacks: {
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken
    session.user.id = token.id
    
    return session
  }
}
```

and add the id to session from use or token object.
ref : https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks